# Checkbox - cant seem to check them

Tags: php, checkbox

I have seen a thousand different ways of doing checkboxes, but my eyes are tired trying to work out why I simply cannot echo variables as checked when the values are true (which they are as I have retrieved them from db and printed them out):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="headlines" value="true" <?php if($headlines=="true"){ echo "checked=checked";} ?> /> Headlines<br />
```

Headlines has been pulled from the database and a variable set based on the row, I have printed it and its true so it must be in the code above.

I have also tried:

`<input type="checkbox" name="headlines" <?php if($row['headlines'] === TRUE){ echo "checked=checked";} ?>/>Headlines<br />`

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the second "checked" in quotes

```
<input checked="checked" />
```

You can use single or double, but you need to cope with this in your echo.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="headlines" value="true" <?php if($headlines=="true"){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /> Headlines<br />
```

(Just a note that this assumes you are writing XHTML. If you are writing HTML then you just need 'checked' and not the full 'checked="checked"'. You cabn also miss off the closing / in the `<br />` etc.)

Comment: And see John's coment below (got my +1). If $headlines has come from a database then it's probably a string (so you should be OK); but if it calculated boolean in your PHP, then you'll need the to treat as a boolean, not a string. Don't get them confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($headlines=="true")
```

"true" is a string, do you maybe want to check that it is true?

```
if($headlines==true)
```

The following works for me in chrome:

```
<?php $headlines = true; ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="headlines" value="true" <?php if($headlines==true){ echo "checked=checked";} ?> /> Headlines<br />
```

As Robbie said, you should also surround the checked value in quotes.